# swig: how to add context manager methods to opaque handle?

Tags: python, swig

when swigging opaque handles (in my case, pointers to some library internal struct), how can we add context manager methods..?

and why do I have to make up fake stuff to pass some silly quality filter, which doesn't tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

not that hard in the end, but perhaps this can save someone some time and frustration.

insert a proxy class "Product", disable constructor (can't do sizeof as it's internal) and destructor, and finally add shadow methods:

```
%rename(Product) product_struct;
%nodefaultctor product_struct;
%nodefaultdtor product_struct;
struct product_struct
{
    %shadow
    %{
        def __enter__(self):
            return self

        def __exit__(self, t, v, t2):
            library.close(self)
    %}
};
```